# Wedge product and point pattern distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, vector-spaces, exterior-algebra, clifford-algebras

As I understand a wedge product in two dimensions considers bivectors as natural extesion of vectors and assigns a magnitude (the area of the parellogram encolsed by the vectors) and a direction.

If there is a distribution of points in a plane, is there any meaningful way we can assign a "direction" to the distribution taking a wedge product between all pairs of vectors? For example, if all the points lie in one direction then each pair of their wedge products will be zero and distribution will have a zero "direction". I think such a distribution is a [truncated Generalized Pareto Distribution, Beta distribution, or power distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114481/what-is-the-name-of-a-distribution-within-a-b-but-with-a-sloped-straight-li).
In general it wil be good to know if there could be a meaningful association of a "direction" to a distribution, if such a thing could be defined.

Comment: Are the points ordered? If not, then obviously the answer is "no", since $\vec u\wedge\vec v=-\vec v\wedge\vec u$. If they're ordered, then you have a piecewise-linear curve or a polygon.

Comment: Thanks. Good point. How about if we impose a condition that we don't consider a pair twice, and always consider the pair where the enclosed angle is measured anti-clockwise?

Comment: Then you're defining the direction as always anticlockwise.

Comment: That's right for any two pairs of points but not for the entire set of points.

Comment: Perhaps you're confused about the meaning of "direction" for bivectors. See my comments under [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4624626/472818). In 2D, the "direction" is not like north/south/east/west; it just corresponds to the _sign_ of the angle measure (in the interval $[-180^\circ,+180^\circ]$).