# Help with intuitively understanding why the space of bivectors from 4D Euclidean space is 6 dimensional

Tags: vector-spaces, geometric-algebras

The wedge  product of two 4D Euclidean space vectors is of dimension 6. I can understand mathematically that the six basis vectors are linearly independent, from the math itself. But I fail to see this intuitively. My confusion is the following:

Each basis vector represents an oriented area inside 4D space, perpendicular to the two basis vectors used in the wedge product. We can add two of these areas and obtain another area. I understand that the orientation of the areas add in a different way that 4D vector do, but I cannot see how or in what way this can result in a vector space of area orientations that is 6 dimensional, rather than 4 dimensional. Is there an easy way to visualize why this is so? (or, did I state something wrong?)

Comment: I think "perpendicular to the two basis vectors" is wrong. It's parallel.

Comment: @mr_e_man I meant the orientation of the plane.

Comment: Yes, the plane/area is parallel to the two basis vectors.

Comment: @mr_e_man the orientation of an area is perpendicular to the plane, right?

Comment: No, that's just a 3D hack, representing bivectors as vectors by Hodge duality.

Comment: The orientation is the plane itself.

Comment: @mr_e_man oh, I am more confused now than before. aren't an infinite number of direction inside a plane? what does orientation mean in such a case? is orientation the same as direction, or are they different?

Comment: A bivector is a 2D plane, with a sense of clockwise/anticlockwise within the plane, and a magnitude (a positive scalar, the area). A vector is a 1D line, with a sense of forward/backward along the line, and a magnitude (the length). Of course there are infinitely many lines in a plane. -- Words like "direction" and "orientation" have varying meanings.

Comment: @mr_e_man ohhhhh thanks.

Comment: I don’t think there’s any real geometry here, it’s just combinatorics. If you insist off geometry, you can interpret this as saying fix four generic (i.e. linearly independent) vectors in R4, then you may always find 6 distinct planes (bivectors) associated to these four vectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the fact that there are six planes in 4D which are pair-wise partially orthogonal to each other. Partially orthogonal means one of the planes contains at least one vector which is orthogonal to the other plane. Total orthogonality (meaning all pairs of vectors, one from each plane, are orthogonal) implies partial orthogonality.

We can see this directly from the standard basis. First, $e_1\wedge e_2$ and $e_3\wedge e_4$ are totally orthogonal. Then we just take one vector from each in every way we can:
$$
  e_1\wedge e_3,\quad
  e_1\wedge e_4,\quad
  e_2\wedge e_3,\quad
  e_2\wedge e_4.
$$
Convince yourself that all six of these planes are pair-wise partially orthogonal.

Suppose there is a seventh plane $B$. There cannot be a nonzero vector in $B$ orthogonal to all the other planes, since then that vector would be orthogonal to all $e_i$ and hence would be zero. So for at least one of the standard planes $E$, there is no $v \in B$ orthogonal to $E$, but there is $v \in E$ orthogonal to $B$. This is impossible for two planes, so $B$ does not exist.

---

You should also convince yourself that the geometric algebra dot product of two bivectors $B_1\cdot B_2 = 0$ iff $B_1$ and $B_2$ are partially orthogonal.

Answer (score 4):

A basis for space of bivectors consists of pairs of vectors from a basis for the the original space, and
$$
\binom{4}{2} = 6. 
$$
We can list them explicitly:
\begin{array}{cccc} 
v_1 \wedge v_2 & v_1 \wedge v_3 & v_1 \wedge v_4 \\
               & v_2 \wedge v_3 & v_2 \wedge v_4 \\
               &                & v_3 \wedge v_4 
\end{array}
and see that there are $6$ of them.

Each of these $v_i \wedge v_j$ describes a plane $\Pi_{ij} = \operatorname{span}\{v_i, v_j\} \subset \mathbb{R}^4$, together with an orientation.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was not clear enough,   I understand the math, but I cannot visualize it. What I cannot understand is how  that is geometrically possible (as opposed to the math) if those bivectors are interpreted as oriented areas. That is, how can you have 6 linearly independent orientations in 4D space? shouldn't you be limited to only 4?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$, since $2 + 1 = 3$, a plane has codimension $1$, so there is a unique independent direction orthogonal to the plane. Thus, you can characterize a plane by bivectors $\{v_1 \wedge v_2, v_1 \wedge v_3, v_2 \wedge v_3\}$ or their orthogonal directions $\{v_3, v_2, v_1\}$, respectively. And of course $\binom{3}{2} = \binom{3}{1} = 3$...

Comment: Does that mean that you can find 6 planes in 4D space that are each perpendicular to each other?

Comment: ... So, in $\mathbb{R}^4$, you might be thinking of hyperplanes (subspaces of codimension $1$), which are *tri*vectors, with basis 
$$
\{v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge v_3, 
v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge v_4, 
v_1 \wedge v_3 \wedge v_4, 
v_2 \wedge v_3 \wedge v_4\}
$$
or their orthogonal vectors $\{v_4, v_3, v_2, v_1\}$, respectively. There are $\binom{4}{3} = \binom{4}{1} = 4$ of *these*. But, these are not *bi*vectors!

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^4$, the set of vector orthogonal to a give plane (meaning, that each is perpendicular to each vector in the plane) don't just form a line like in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but rather an entire plane. One way to think about this is that you can parametrize a closed circular orbit flying *around* a given plane because there is a plane's worth of orthogonal directions in which to form this circle.

Comment: Thanks, I need to think more about it. in the mean time, so I can accept your answer, is it true that you can find 6 planes in 4D space that are each perpendicular to each other? Or is my interpretation wrong?

Comment: What does it mean for two planes to be *perpendicular to each other*? Subspaces $U$ and $V$ can be *orthogonal*, meaning that $u \cdot v = 0$ for any $u \in U$ and any $v \in V$. In $\mathbb{R}^4$, being orthogonal to a given plane imposes $2$ independent linear constraints on a given vector, meaning that the space of such vectors is of codimension $2$, hence it is $4 - 2 = 2$ dimensional. Thus, these vectors form a unique plane, the *orthogonal complement* of the given plane. So, only **2** planes can be orthogonal in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 2):

The geometric aspect provides motivation. Consider projective 3-space over an arbitrary field (There is nothing special about $\mathbb R$ in this context.) where the points are given by 4 homogeneous coordinates, i.e. ratios (x:y:z:t). Two points $P_1=(x_1:y_1:z_1:t_1),P_2=(x_2:y_2:z_2:t_2)$ are distinct iff the rank of $\begin{bmatrix}x_1&y_1&z_1&t_1 \\x_2&y_2&z_2&t_2\end{bmatrix}$ is 2. The Grassman-Plucker coordinates of the line $L$ joining $P_1$ and $P_2$ are the point with 6 homogeneous coordinates$(\ell:m:n:\ell^{\prime}:m^{\prime}:n^{\prime})$ in projective 5-space where $$\ell=\begin{vmatrix}x_1&x_2\\t_1&t_2 \end{vmatrix},m=\begin{vmatrix} y_1&y_2\\t_1&t_2\end{vmatrix},n=\begin{vmatrix}z_1&z_2\\t_1&t_2 \end{vmatrix},$$ $$\ell^{\prime}=\begin{vmatrix}y_1&y_2\\z_1&z_2 \end{vmatrix},m^{\prime}=-\begin{vmatrix} x_1&x_2\\z_1&z_2\end{vmatrix},n^{\prime}=\begin{vmatrix}x_1&x_2\\y_1&y_2 \end{vmatrix}.$$ Then  the point $(\ell:m:n:\ell^{\prime}:m^{\prime}:n^{\prime})$ is independent of which two points on $L$ are used. Moreover, $$\ell \ell^{\prime}+mm^{\prime}+nn^{\prime}=0$$ and there is a bijection between lines in projective 3-space and points on this quadric surface in projective 5-space.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your intuition fails is that in 3D to every plane there is *one* normal vector. This means you automatically associate a bivector in 3D with its normal vector. 3 axes = 3 bivectors right? Well, in 4D there can be 2 linearly independent normal vectors to every plane. I made a diagram of this to make it visually more clear. The color of each bivector is a mix of the colors of the basis vectors it is composed of. For example cyan = blue + green. I also show each vector that the plane is normal to.

In 3D:
[image]

---

In 4D:
[image]